# Add function with custom parameter to wp footer

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm building a simple shortcode plugin. One of the shortcodes requires jQuery in the footer to activate tabs with uniqid div ids. I'm building the jQuery with the following function:

```
function footer_scripts($id_array){

    foreach($id_array as $id) {
        $tab_loop .= '$(\'.nav-tabs a[href="#tabs-'.$id.'"]\').tab(\'show\');';
    }

     $return = 'jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        // var touched = false;
        e.preventDefault();';
     $return .= $tab_loop;
     $return .= '});';

     return $return;
 }
```

Then calling that function within the function that builds the tabs like so:

```
 function tab_group($atts, $content) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
         // Option to use tabs or pills and open or closed framing
        'nav'   => 'tabs',
        'style'     => 'framed',
    ), $atts));

    $GLOBALS['tab_count'] = 0;

    do_shortcode($content);

    if( is_array( $GLOBALS['tabs'] ) ){

        // Create an array of IDs to pass to the footer js function

        $id_array = array();

        // Create arrays for the foreach loop to contain the tab selectors and contents. We will pull this apart outside of the loop using implode()

        foreach( $GLOBALS['tabs'] as $tab ){
            $id_array[] = $tab['id'];
            $tabs[] = '<li class=""><a href="#tabs-'.$tab['id'].'" data-toggle="'.substr($nav,0,-1).'" title="'.$tab['title'].'">'.$tab['title'].'</a></li>';
            $tab_contents[] = '<div id="tabs-'.$tab['id'].'"><h3>'.$tab['title'].'</h3>'.$tab['content'].'</div>';
        }

        footer_scripts($id_array);

        $return = "\n".'<!-- Tabs Shortcode -->'."\n".'<ul class="nav nav-'.$nav.'">'.implode( "\n", $tabs ).'</ul>'."\n".'<!-- Tabs Content -->'."\n".'<div class="tab-content">'.implode( "\n", $tab_contents ).'</div>'."\n";
    }
    return $return;
 }
```

So my question now is how to put this newly minted block of code into the footer. I know that I can call a function using `add_action('wp_footer'`... but it doesn't seem to accept custom parameters.

I hope this is enough information!

Thanks!

Comment: You are on the right path, however you need to change your function so that it doesn't take parameters and instead use a provider to provide the options.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't seem to find any resources on how to set this up and am not quite clear on what you mean by "provider".

Comment: basically you must set the parameters somewhere else, for example a database, and then your function can call a function that may provide the required parameters. For example, create a get_widget_parameter(x_parameter) function, or get the parameters that this function require from wordpress configuration for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it's really a bad practice to mix ur php code with javascript code, create a .js file and add it to footer : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script (set footer to true to include ur javacript file in the footer);
Then for each item add a css class, then in your javascript file u can refrence all the items with that css class.

Comment: That's how I began to do it, except that each tab is activated individually based on ID. The ID is generated using uniqid() at runtime.

Comment: In your js file you could do 
$(".nav-tabs a").each(function(){
 $(this).tab("show");
});
to loop over all the tabs (with unique ids) and make them into a tab, although i'm not sure what jquery tab plugin u're using, for instance in twitter bootstrap tabs, tab's doesn't get initiated like what u're doing

Comment: Awesome, that does it. Thank you for your help Sam.